# What is the best way to trigger a journey from a mobile App?

Tags: mobilepush

We are in the process of designing the best IOs between MC and our App. We'd thought at first to simply use the SDK and trigger a register App Event. Unfortunately, this can't be used as of now.

So what is the best way to trigger a journey, then ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we did it in our Android App in Kotlin quiet easily.
You can do this

1. Create a package with a server to server API component in setup
2. Create a Event Entry in JB
3. Create a Journey sourced with this Entry and filling a new DE
4. Do whatever you wish in this journey
5. From the App, require an auth token from MC (see below)
6. From the App perform a POST request containing JSON payload (see below)

We use Volley as an HTTP client, and securely store creds in the App.

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity!!.applicationContext)
val auth = JSONObject()
auth.put("grant_type", "client_credentials")
auth.put("client_id", MC_CLIENT_ID)
auth.put("client_secret", MC_CLIENT_SECRET)
auth.put("scope", "journeys_read list_and_subscribers_read")
auth.put("account_id", MC_MID)

val req = JsonObjectRequest(
  Request.Method.POST, 
  MC_AUTH + "/v2/token", 
  auth, 
  { response -> triggerJourney(response.get("access_token").toString(), sdk, queue) },
  { error -> /*whatever handling*/ }
)
queue.add(req)
```

Then you actually trigger the journey with a fresh token (which you should cache). We use a class extending JsonObjectRequest with the sole purpose of dealing with HTTP headers :

```
val contactKey = sdk.sdkState.optJSONObject("RegistrationManager")?.optJSONObject("current_registration")!!.get("subscriberKey").toString()
val trigger = JSONObject()
trigger.put("ContactKey", contactKey)
trigger.put("EventDefinitionKey", MC_BUY_JOURNEY) // Trigger definition from MC
val command = JSONObject()
command.put("Your Arg","whatever value") // Will be stored in receiving DE and available as journey data
val req = BearerRequest(
  Request.Method.POST, 
  MC_REST + "/interaction/v1/events", trigger,
  { response -> myDisplay(response.toString()) },
  { error -> /*whatever handling*/ },token
)
queue.add(req)
```

Boom, you registered users are injected in your journey.

Comment: Thanks ! How do you "securely store creds" ?

Comment: Use buildConfigField in gradle, and do not promote them to your repository ;)